# Altering values of a list in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to translate '`methuselahs`' into binary code. All the dots ('.') should become 0, and all the O's ('O') should become 1.

I currently have a code that does work, but it will only return the first list of list_of_lists..

```
list_of_lists = [['.O'],['...O'],['OO..OOO']]

def read_file(list_of_lists):

     """Reads a file and returns a 2D list containing the pattern.
     O = Alive
     . = Dead
     """

     end_list = []
     sub_list = []

     for A_List in list_of_lists:
         for A_String in A_List:
             for item in A_String:

 #Adding 0's and 1's to sub_list when given the right input
                 if item == '.':

                     sub_list.append(0)

                 elif item == 'O':

                     sub_list.append(1)

 #Adding the sub
             end_list.append(sub_list)

         return end_list
```

Output :

```
[[0,1]]
```

But Expected Output:

```
[[0,1],[0,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1]]
```

Does anybody know how I can get the code to change all the lists instead of just the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outdent `return end_list` to the `for A_List in list_of_lists:` indentation level.

And bring `sub_list = []` into that `for`-loop:

```
def read_file(list_of_lists):
    """Reads a file and returns a 2D list containing the pattern.
    O = Alive
    . = Dead
    """
    end_list = []
    for A_List in list_of_lists:
        sub_list = []
        for A_String in A_List:
            for item in A_String:
            #Adding 0's and 1's to sub_list when given the right input
                if item == '.':
                    sub_list.append(0)
                elif item == 'O':
                    sub_list.append(1)
            #Adding the sub
            end_list.append(sub_list)
    return end_list
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been messing with this for two hours, I now understand what I did wrong. Also thank you for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2):

Two issues in your code -

1. You are returning from within the `for` loop, hence you return as soon as you finish the first sublist. Hence the output you are getting.
2. You are not redefining `sub_list` within the for loop , without that there would only be one `sub_list` added multiple times and any changes you make to it would be reflected in all sublists.

But you don't need all this , you can use list comprehension to achieve the same thing -

```
def read_file(list_of_lists):
    return [[1 if ch == 'O' else 0 
             for st in sub_list for ch in st] 
             for sub_list in list_of_lists]
```

Demo -

```
>>> def read_file(list_of_lists):
...     return [[1 if ch == 'O' else 0
...              for st in sub_list for ch in st]
...              for sub_list in list_of_lists]
...
>>> read_file([['.O'],['...O'],['OO..OOO']])
[[0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: I would never have come up with a solution like this, but it works perfectly! Thanks for answering so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. But problem in `return end_list` indentation level. When you return in `for loop`, after first iteration your function return and does not occur other iteration.

Try this, your code is modified:

```
list_of_lists = [['.O'],['...O'],['OO..OOO']]

def read_file(list_of_lists):

     """Reads a file and returns a 2D list containing the pattern.
     O = Alive
     . = Dead
     """

     end_list = []

     for A_List in list_of_lists:
         sub_list = []
         for A_String in A_List:
             for item in A_String:

 #Adding 0's and 1's to sub_list when given the right input
                 if item == '.':

                     sub_list.append(0)

                 elif item == 'O':

                     sub_list.append(1)

 #Adding the sub
             end_list.append(sub_list)

     return end_list
```

Output:

```
[[0,1],[0,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I this it's okk now